# Hide wordpress source code

Tags: url-rewriting

Hey guys Iv searched all over maybe Im not using the right terms. Im trying to stop the index off my wordpress site tree structure like wp-content wp-content\plugins etc on the sources panel in chrome dev tools, but with no luck. Iv tried adding some .htaccess rules to solve the issue. Iv also added some plugins but they all let you rename , but not to hidw cpmpletly hope someone could help cheers

Comment: Dev tools aren’t actually showing the file real file structure. It’s just organising resources based on their URLs to make them easier to browse. Chrome doesn’t know anything about your server’s directory structure. It just sees that an image, for example, has the URL `/wp-content/uploads` and *assumes* that there is a folder called wp-content with a folder called uploads in it. It’s not doing anything nefarious like scanning your server.

Comment: Cheers whoof good to know. But is there a way of hiding it?

Comment: No. To serve files to users the browser needs to know where to get them. The dev tools tell you where these files are coming from. This is the same for literally every website.